# Screen Brightness accidently set to dimmest (blank screen) Android-x86_64-8.1-r1

Tags: 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo, android-x86, screen-brightness

I installed Andriod-x86 on a tablet and was happy with the results untill I changed the screen brightness setting. It accidentally got set to zero brightness. Now the GUI is not obtained when android boots. For last few hours trying to set brightness in debug mode with no success so far.

I am not able to connect wifi in debug mode either to doenload and try other tools as suggested at some forums. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Do you have a custom recovery installed, such as TWRP?

Comment: I did not know before your comment that there exists such a thing as "Team Win Recovery Project". Wonder what are my options now?

Comment: Are you confident that you can _unlock_ the device once its booted?  You could go find a similar tablet, boot both at the same time, and perform the same actions in the same relative screen area on each - that is, navigate to settings via the non-blank-screen tablet while touching the same areas on the blank-screen tablet; essentially mirroring the touch targets.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My father restored the display for me doing the suggested blind clicks.

Answer (score 1):

This method requires [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb):

With your device plugged in, issue a screen brightness change request:

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 255
```

The number at the end of that command is a number from 0-255, where 0 is dimmest and 255 is brightest.

Note: if the above command doesn't work, you might have to issue this commend first:

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0
```

Comment: adb does not work either on android-x86.

Comment: Thank you for the link. So this is a client server connection and the command is sent remotely. I had been issuing it on the same machine. Will check it tonight after work.